# Iterator validity

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm looking for a more in depth explanation here, not just how to get working code.  I know how to write much shorter code to erase elements.  I wrote this test code here to pinpoint points of failure upon deletion.  It would seem that not only the i iterator becomes invalid but also the .end() iterator... and that is interesting.

Why is that this works?

```
    deque<shared_ptr<Vehicle>> data;
    data.push_back( shared_ptr<Vehicle>(new Vehicle("porsche")) );
    data.push_back( shared_ptr<Vehicle>(new Vehicle("fiat")) );
    data.push_back( shared_ptr<Vehicle>(new Vehicle("fiat")) );
    data.push_back( shared_ptr<Vehicle>(new Vehicle("bmw")) );
    data.push_back( shared_ptr<Vehicle>(new Vehicle("fiat")) );    

    auto end = data.end();
    for(auto i = data.begin(); i != end;)
    {

        if( (*i)->getName() == "fiat" )
        {
            auto ti = i;
            ++ti;
            end = data.end();   //above erase, works but not logical
            data.erase(i);
            i=ti;
        }
        else
        {
           ++i;
           end = data.end();
        }
    }
```

but this does not work?

```
deque<shared_ptr<Vehicle>> data;
data.push_back( shared_ptr<Vehicle>(new Vehicle("porsche")) );
data.push_back( shared_ptr<Vehicle>(new Vehicle("fiat")) );
data.push_back( shared_ptr<Vehicle>(new Vehicle("fiat")) );
data.push_back( shared_ptr<Vehicle>(new Vehicle("bmw")) );
data.push_back( shared_ptr<Vehicle>(new Vehicle("fiat")) );    

auto end = data.end();
for(auto i = data.begin(); i != end;)
{

    if( (*i)->getName() == "fiat" )
    {
        auto ti = i;
        ++ti;
        data.erase(i);
        end = data.end();   //Bellow erase...more logical but crashes
        i=ti;
    }
    else
    {
       ++i;
       end = data.end();
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that there is some implementation level issue here.  Perhaps a compiler bug.  Using GCC 4.8.2.

Comment: You likely have a bug elsewhere in the code that results in undefined behavior. You will need to edit your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Iterator behavior varies depending on the type of container.  What, exactly, is `data`?

Comment: Code added.  Guaranteed no error else place.  ie. the class Vehicle is implemented properly, etc.  I'm not gonna post it to keep the code focused and clean.

Comment: Agree with answer below and the reason first code snipped works is called "undefined behavior".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're invoking Undefined Behavior.  From the language spec, about `deque::erase`:

> An erase operation that erases the last element of a deque invalidates only the past-the-end
>   iterator and all iterators and references to the erased elements. An erase operation that erases the
>   first element of a deque but not the last element invalidates only iterators and references to the erased
>   elements. An erase operation that erases neither the first element nor the last element of a deque
>   invalidates the past-the-end iterator and all iterators and references to all the elements of the deque.

In your case, your `end` iterator is always getting clobbered, and it's just luck that it works at all.  The crash in the second case is likely due to operations on `i`, not the `data.end` call.